# Make text float-right in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, text, textview

I'm trying to achieve some text layout in Android a little like `float="right"` in HTML. I have two items of text to go in a certain area of my screen. I'd like one of them to be left-aligned in a TextView, and one of them to be right-aligned, like this (where the `|` at either end represent the enclosing container):-

```
| First text item      label |
```

So far this sounds easy: I could do it with two `TextView`s in a `RelativeLayout`, the right-hand one set to `layout_alignParentRight="true"` or `layout_gravity="right"`. But there's also the case where the left-hand text is too long to fit in the remaining space. With a `RelativeLayout` it would overlap the right-hand text, but I want it to break into two lines in this case:-

```
| This text is way too long  |
|                      label |
```

and similarly, if the left-hand text flows onto multiple lines, I want the right-hand text to fit on the same line if possible:-

```
| This text doesn't fit on   |
| one line             label |
```

Because `View`s in Android are always rectangular, it seems like it would be impossible to make this last example work with two `TextView`s even if I wrote a custom `Layout`. I looked into using a `Spannable` to let me put all the text in one `TextView`, but again, `AlignmentSpan` is a `ParagraphStyle`, so it doesn't look like it'll be able to put the label on the same line as the left-hand text that way. Is there some other kind of text span I can use to achieve this, or even a completely different method?

At the moment, it looks like I'll have to either put the text in HTML and use a `WebView` (not great, as the view is to go in a list item), or write a custom `TextView`-like widget.

Comment: have you considered a custom view?

Comment: As I say at the end of the question, that's my last resort, but I'd like to avoid that cost if I can.

Comment: if you ever listen to the google I/O talks by romain guy, he always recommends using a custom view. it gives you better performance and allows a lot of customization without creating large view hierarchies

Answer (score 5):

Add `android:gravity="right"` (not the same as `layout_gravity`) to the right one but also add `android:layout_alignBottom`and refer to id of the other text view. multiline to true etc I assume you already have. Keep the `alignParentRight` and `alignParentLeft` respectively.

To be clear, while they are rectangular they can still overlap if you want, using `RelativeLayout` (or `FrameLayout` etc)

Alternative way, try this:
 swap `android:layout_alignBottom="@id..."` with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the *right* side text view.

Getting the third example and the second example to work at the same time though with a simple RelativeLayout, hmm...

Comment: This doesn't seem like it will work for my second example, where the left-hand text just fits on a line and the right-hand text needs to go underneath it instead of on the right. From what I know of `RelativeLayout`, it seems like the text will overlap in that case. Would you agree?

Comment: Ah, I was thinking mostly about your last example. What if you swap the `layout_alignBottom="@id..."` with `layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the right one then...

Comment: Yes of course, I'm unable to test myself currently, should've been obvious. Sorry about that.